# Can only take 12MP photos on my 16MP Sony DSC H100

Tags: camera-settings, resolution

I bought this camera at a quarter of its price and just noticed I seemingly can't take pictures at its full resolution (16MP). The only available options are 2 and 12MP.
Any clues?

Comment: The usual advice about a hard reset and firmware check applies I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you have not selected Panorama Image Size. Most cameras will crop the full size 16mp 4:3 image to create the wide 16:9 Panorama Image which is only 12mp.

[User Guide: Still Image Size / Panorama Image Size / Movie Size](https://helpguide.sony.net/gbmig/44390041/v1/eng/contents/04/02/04/04.html)

[image]